# jquery selector: reference class inside of where i clicked:

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have this html:

```
<div class="title"><img class="arrow" src="rightarrow.gif" />Title</div>
```

i have  this click event:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.title').live('click', function () {

            //NEED SOMETHING HERE TO CHANGE SOURCE                 
            $(".arrow").attr("src", "downarrow.gif");
        });
    });
```

as you can see i want to change the src attribute of the image. my selector above works, but there are other items on the page with class ="arrow", so i need a way to just select this one instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to constrain the selector to only find elements contained within the element that was clicked (represented by `$(this)`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.title').live('click', function() {
        $(this).find('.arrow').attr('src', 'downarrow.gif');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Replace with this:

`$(".arrow").attr({"src": "downarrow.gif"});`

Comment: How is this "a way to just select this one instance"?

Comment: @BoltClock sorry, I didn't read the full question. My mistake. :) Definitely it should be `$(this).find("img").attr({"src":"axy.png"});`