# Jquery selector element inside other

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having a issue trying to built a nice "products" page, I have the html:

```
    <div class="product-box-2">
     <a href="img/produtos/1-lightbox.jpg" class="lightbox"><img src="img/produtos/1.jpg" alt=""></a>
     <p class="legend">>> Vero mlkshk velit, freegan ullamco commodo put a bird on it cred synth kogi, Vero mlkshk velit, freegan ullamco commodo put a bird on it cred synth kogi.</p>
     <a href="img/produtos/1-lightbox.jpg" class="ampliar lightbox">clique para ampliar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="product-box-2">
     <a href="img/produtos/1-lightbox.jpg" class="lightbox"><img src="img/produtos/1.jpg" alt=""></a>
     <p class="legend">>> Vero mlkshk velit, freegan ullamco commodo put a bird on it cred synth kogi, Vero mlkshk velit, freegan ullamco commodo put a bird on it cred synth kogi.</p>
     <a href="img/produtos/1-lightbox.jpg" class="ampliar lightbox">clique para ampliar</a>
    </div>
```

And so many times it's needed. And then I try to put a nice effect on the .legend, with CSS to seting "display:none" and the Jquery:

```
    $('.product-box-2 a').mouseenter(
    function(){
    $('.legend').fadeIn();
});

$('.product-box-2').mouseleave(
    function(){
    $('.legend').fadeOut();
});
```

But I have the same classes, and so, all legends appear when I put my mouse over some of the .product-box-2 a... And I have no idea how to select only the .legend inside the .product-box-2 a there I'm in.

If you want to see this in action, [here it is!](http://viotidesign.com.br/clientes/glafcon/produtos.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery selector: reference class inside of where i clicked:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695804/jquery-selector-reference-class-inside-of-where-i-clicked) -- different event, same problem. The jQuery documentation is very good, I suggest you have a look at it: http://api.jquery.com/.

Comment: Yeap, was the same problem, sorry about that... But sometimes happen that I know where to search, but don't know "how" to search, so I need a bit of human help, even in this case, as you can see I'm really in the beginning of my studies, then sometimes is really hard know "what" to as for the internet.

Comment: No need to be sorry, I'm not blaming you :) I know it's sometimes difficult to find the answer through search. I'd just be happy if more people would would vote to close as a duplicate (in general) so that we don't clutter the page with the same answers over and over again :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrict the scope of the inner selector to the element on which the event occurred by giving it the element as the context.  See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) for the signature that accepts a context.

```
$('.product-box-2 a').mouseenter(
   function(){
    $('.legend',$(this).closest('div')).fadeIn();
});
$('.product-box-2').mouseleave(
    function(){
    $('.legend',this).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried it but doesn't work here, and show no error to, so I don't have any idea of why doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the anchor tag selector, you'll have to go up to the closest div first as the context.

Answer (score 2):

you can try `.children([Selector])` as well

```
$('.product-box-2 a').mouseenter(
    function(){
    $(this).children('.legend').fadeIn();
});

$('.product-box-2').mouseleave(
    function(){
    $(this).children('.legend').fadeOut();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
$(this).find('.legend').fadeIn();
```

In this case `$(this)` refers to the element that triggered an event and `.find()` looks only among its children.

Comment: Many thanks, it worked.
But have only one bad thing, now I have to set
`$('.product-box-2 a').mouseenter` to `$('.product-box-2').mouseenter`

That means, some parts of my `.product-box-2` will show the legend without be a link...

Comment: @Eduardo Ruiz: I cannot get what you mean

Comment: In this solution I have to use the father element to trigger, but what I want is to use a image and a link(brothers of `.legend`) to trigger the event, so the answer above the yours solve the thing.
Ah, and thanks for the explanation about `.find()` that's new to me.